# jQuery generated responsive Select menu not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, navigation

I am using jQuery to convert a navigation menu to a select list when the browser window is small, for a responsive design. However, selecting Options of select list redirect to appropriate page in Firefox and Opera, on Webkit based browsers, selecting an option does not do anything.

Live demo - http://emoeco.com

```
$('ul.menu').each(function(){

                var action="loadPage(this.form.elements[0])";
                var form=$(document.createElement('form')).insertBefore($(this));
                $(form).attr({
                method: 'post'
                });
                var select=$(document.createElement('select')).appendTo(form);
                $(select).attr("onchange", action);
                 $('>li a', this).each(function(){
                 var a=$(this).click(function(){
                 window.location.href=this.href;
                 }),
                 option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html()).click(function(){
                 a.click();
                 });
                 });

                 });
```

Comment: There are many errors on that page, first try to resolve those errors. One javascript error can cause the whole javascript to stop.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should open a JavaScript console and look at the errors. Most of them are due to files not being found.

Second, just looking at the heads tag makes me die a little inside. I know this is not the purpose of your question, but you create enormous overheads by loading the same things twice or more. Please spend the 5 minutes needed to fix that; the site will load a million times faster

Third, if I understand your question right, you should do it in a way that the user has to click a button to traverse to a page. Plus, instead of completely removing the menu, why don't you scale it?

Fourth, if you dislike Thirds, why not dump the whole anchor thing, and just use select's native 'change' event?

```
$('select').change(function() {
    location.href = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
});
```

Edit: As to why it doesn't work only in WebKit, it's because they don't tie the click event to the 'option' element. At least that's what I think: You can try [this example](http://jsbin.com/elapu3/) (add /edit to the url to see the source code.) Tested working in FireFox, got nothing in Chrome